# How close do two waves need to be to able to superpose?

Tags: waves, superposition

DO two waves need to cross paths to be able to superimpose or can they superpose over a distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wave consists of a series of fluctuations away from some static status which travels through space as time progresses. For sound or water or a string, the fluctuations are  displacements of the medium through which the wave is travelling. An electromagnetic wave consists of fluctuating electric and magnetic fields.

If two (or more) waves are travelling through a region of space simultaneously the fluctuations which one wave would cause by itself is added to the common-type fluctuation another wave would cause by itself *at each individual point in space*. That's one part of superposition.

Another part of superposition is that the possible fluctuation of the wave at other points is not affected by the resulting superposition at the first point, i.e., the superposition of two waves at location A does not *change* the behavior of either wave at other points.

So, yes, superposition only occurs when two or more waves are acting at a common point simultaneously. But they may be acting simultaneously at more than one common point. An example of this is standing waves in a string. Waves are superposing along the whole length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

They have to be right on top of one another. And the places where they are right on top of one another are the only places where they superpose.